# osm2pgsql Error - no schema has been selected to create in

Tags: osm2pgsql

I have a Postgres database with PostGIS and hstore extensions created. The data tables are in a schema called geodata with the search path set

```
ALTER DATABASE wapdb1 SET search_path = 'postgres','geodata' , 'hstore';
```

osm2pgsql script:

```
osm2pgsql -c -d wapdb1 -U postgres -H localhost  -S  C:\default.style  --hstore C:\england-latest.osm.pbf
```

It is failing with an error - no schema has been selected to create in. Do I need to specify the schema to create in using osm2pgsql? If so how?

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What does SHOW search_path; return? Also, I'm not sure it it matters, but with set search_path, you don't need apostrophes around the schema names. Finally, if you are running this from psql, you will probably have to exit and restart for the effect to take place. To avoid this you can try setting `set session search_path = geodata, hstore, public`;

Comment: Thanks for responding John. SHOW search_path is returning postgres, geodata, hstore, geodoata. When I run ALTER DATABASE wapdb1 SET search_path TO geodata, hstore, public; it doesn't change. I'm running the queries from SQL Editor as I cannot get psql to run despite locating it and setting the System Path. Maybe these two problems are related.

Comment: Hm, yes, I would think that getting psql to work would be a move in the right direction.

Comment: OK psql is working now and SHOW search_path; is returning geodata, hstore, public  I have closed the connection \q and then run the script which returns messages about create table planet_osm_point and  some key value pairs that look like field names and then ERROR: type "hstore" does not exist etc